# Error on relationship where the principal's key is not the primary key - ef6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

These are my C# classes and I'm using MySql with EF:

**--- A Table  ---**

```
int ID //(AI,PK)
Collection<C> cList
```

**--- B Table  ---**

```
int ID // (AI, NN, UNIQUE)
int B1 //(pk)
int B2 //(pk)
Collection<C> cList
```

**--- C Table ---**

```
int ID //(AI, NN, UNIQUE)

int A_ID //(pk) - table A, field ID
virtual <A> objectA

int B_ID //(pk) - table b, field ID
virtual <B> objectB
```

**table C Mapping :**

```
HasKey(o => new { A_ID = o.A_ID, B_ID = o.B_ID });
            Property(x => x.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
            Property(x => x.A_ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
            Property(x => x.B_ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

HasRequired(x => x.objectA).WithMany(x => x.cList).HasForeignKey(x => x.A_ID);//works
HasRequired(x => x.objectB).WithMany(x => x.cList).HasForeignKey(x => x.B_ID);//FAILS
```

I'm going crazy and googling and googling and googling... Please help!

Comment: and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry... I'd like to know ho to code in the right way  these lines: HasRequired(x => x.objectB).WithMany(x => x.cList).HasForeignKey(x => x.B_ID);